# Summer18: Test only deployment cannot insert a new Master-Detail field

Tags: deployment, master-detail, migration-tool, ci, summer-18

Today SF has just pushed Summer18 (api version 43) to our sandboxes.

And now when our CI process is trying to validate code from branch against empty SF org, it throws bunch of same error messages for each master-Detail field we have in our schema:

```
Test only deployment cannot insert a new Master-Detail field
```

Does it mean that in Summer18 we cannot validate code against empty org anymore? Should it already be deployed with some code?

Currently we are using same set of empty orgs to validate different branches, sometimes they even contain inconsistent changes, i.e. permanently deploying to an org is not an option.

Any help/advice would be appreciated

Comment: Sometimes these error come since SF deployment may still be stabilizing in the background. Did you try again after sometime?

Comment: @RedDevil Two days later - still same error on validation, SF support is looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same issue and SF support came back with following, its a bummer that validation for codebase which has new master-detail cannot be done anymore.

"We've received multiple cases regarding the same issue; R&D has confirmed that this this error is 'Working as Designed' in the Summer 18 release. The error is only thrown in a check-only deployment, there is no change to regular deployments, so a "proper" deployment should have no issue, unless there is a legitimate error. This check-only error is specific to new Master Detail field. "

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been fixed.  We had the same issue on test-only deployments and they no longer throw this error.

Comment: Yep, got confirmation from support, that issue has been fixed. No errors when doing validation deployment from our CI jobs as well.

Comment: We just saw this error in 2021. The comment below showed us The Way - do a "proper" deployment. I would say that this is an ongoing issue, if it is an issue at all.